# Return NSString from a C function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In iOS development, is it possible to use `NSString` and return it from a function?

e.g.

```
(NSString * ) foo {
  return @"";

}
```

This is not an objective c method, just function

Comment: Yes, you can, but you don't do it like that...

Comment: Please learn C before Objective-C. You don't even know the syntax for a C function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, seeing as objective-c objects are just pointers, you can create a C function to return one:

```
NS_RETURNS_RETAINED NSString *myFunction() {
    return [[NSString alloc] init];
}
```

Notice the use of `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED`. This is a hint to ARC and the static analyzer that this function returns a retained value to the receiver, and that it's their responsibility to release it.

If you were returning an autoreleased value, try using `NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED` instead.

Comment: Note that either attribute is sufficient for returning constant strings (and neither one is needed) - I'm just sure that'll be the next questio of OP :)

Comment: @H2CO3 Not necessarily true. With objective-c 2.5 (what I call the addition of the new literals), a NSString literal is not guaranteed to be a constant (e.g. allocated in the executable's memory). It could very well be allocated on the heap at run-time, you don't know.

Comment: That's perfectly true! (But, you know, I have no access to these new tools - I don't know how the new literals work...)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Do you mean if I have `alloc init ` in the return than I should use  `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED`, and if I return `@"xxx"` then I should use `NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED`? What if I don't provide the hints (Assume I am using ARC already)

Comment: @Yoga if you don't provide hints, then for all methods that aren't `alloc` and `init`, NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED is the default.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Shouldn't ARC take care of this already? I have removed and seems my program continue to work, so I am quite confused are these hints still required in ARC mode. My understanding is they are just hints, not a requirement.

Comment: @Yoga, yes, these are hints, not requirements, but then can help with interpolation with non-arc code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the syntax is different:

```
NSString *foo()
{
    return @"bar";
}
```

Comment: And, of course, the file must be a an `m` or `mm` file or have it's file type attribute set appropriately in Info.

Comment: @HotLicks no, it's completely valid to have a C-function in a header file as long as it is defined as `static`, so that you don't run into linker errors. In fact, it's quite common to have a static inline C function in a header, such as `NSMakeRange`.

Comment: @HotLicks not necessarily. 1. Have you used `gcc -x objc foo.someExoticExtension` for forcing the compiler to interpret a file with any extension as a given language? 2. "have it's file type attribute set appropriately in Info" - What's info? What's that file type attribute?

Comment: @H2CO3 'Info' in this case is Xcode's file attributes, which with some of the newer versions allow you to change the type of code compiled without changing the extension.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Thanks for the info. But that's kind of irrelevant (i. e. what if you don't use Xcode?)

Comment: @H2CO3 I agree. In fact, there are excellent 3rd party alternatives to Xcode, such as AppCode by JetBrains (but it costs a fortune). And nothing beats the command line compiler.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII +1 for "nothing beats the command line compiler".

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII -- The point is that, without the right file type, the file will be compiled as C and the the `@` will be a syntax error.

Comment: @HotLicks of course, as both of us probably know without further warning. But if you warn us for it, please at least be correct in the wording. Thanks.

Comment: @HotLicks as long as you aren't `#include`ing this in a .c file, it will not be compiled as C. How a header is compiled completely dependent upon where it is included.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII -- I don't see anywhere where it says it's in an .h file. (And what wording was "wrong"?)

Comment: @HotLicks "And, of course, the file must be a an m or mm file" is you wrote, but it's simply not true.

Comment: @H2CO3 -- OK, "the file must be an m or mm file or have its file type set appropriately in info or otherwise be compiled with a compiler that believes its an Objective C file, or be an h file included in such a file."  Good enough?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *foo()
{
    const char* yourString = "bar";
    NSString* yourNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", yourString];

    return yourNSString;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's a way to return a NSString from a C function, but it's not how you create a NSString from a C-string. Try using `+stringWithUTF8String:` instead.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII this method has an advantage, indeed. It doesn't crash upon the C string being NULL.

Comment: @H2CO3 if your C-string is NULL, then you have other issues to worry about most likely.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII not necessarily... Why wouldn't it be, for example, a valid out-of-range indicator (that is what NULL is for...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not? Check `NSStringFromRect()` and similar for a reference.