# How to return NSString from a function?

Tags: c, nsstring, return

I am trying to learn the ropes a little bit by writing a little hangman application. I have most of the things I need; however, I have a function that prompts the user for a letter (using the old C way) and then converts it into an `NSString` so I can do all the fancy stuff with the `NSString` like easily locate a particular letter or get size.

However, I need to return the `NSString` (pointer) from the function and use it back in main to be passed into other functions.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define WORD_LIST_SIZE 3

void displayBlanks(float numChars);
NSString * askUserForLetter();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    NSString * userLetter;

    int wrongCount = 0;
    int rightCount = 0;

    int randomWordIndex;
    float lettersInWord;

    NSString *wordList[WORD_LIST_SIZE];
    wordList[0] = @"dog";
    wordList[1] = @"bike";
    wordList[2] = @"plane";


    //
    //generates random index for word
    randomWordIndex = arc4random() % WORD_LIST_SIZE;


    //
    //gets the length of the random word
    lettersInWord = [wordList[randomWordIndex] length];


    //
    //Display title and blank
    printf("Guess the letters! Be careful! You may get hung! \n\n");
    displayBlanks(lettersInWord);


    //
    //ask for user letter the first time, return NSSTring 'userLetter'
    askUserForLetter();

    /*
     while (wrongCount < 9 && rightCount < lettersInWord) {
        if ([wordList[randomWordIndex] rangeOfString:userLetter].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"Correct!");
            askUserForLetter();
            rightCount++;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Wrong!");
            askUserForLetter();
            wrongCount++;
        }
    }
     */

    NSLog(@"Your letter is: %@", userLetter);


}
return 0;
}

void displayBlanks(float numChars){
int i;
for (i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
    printf(" _ ");
}
printf("\n\n");
}


NSString * askUserForLetter (){
char userTry;

printf("Enter a letter you think is in the word: ");
scanf("%c", &userTry);
NSString * userGuess = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", userTry];

return userGuess;
}
```

Comment: The way you did it looks right. What's the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196265/return-nsstring-from-a-c-function

Comment: is this actually a C question or is it obj-c?

Comment: Please post code that is as short as possible, only showing the issue.  This code is much too long.

Comment: When I try to use the retuned 'userGuess' from the askForLetter function in main it gives me a null value. I apologize for the lengthy code bit, as I am a new guy on these forums and figured more was better than not enough code.